# why websecurity does not die while sessions die

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am building mvc4 application

i use two databases, the first one is the default databases which i use for connecting and initializing the websecurity connection.

the second one is my own database, so i am using database first approch.

i have this problem,

> the sessoin dies while the websecurity still alive

i use session to konw the type of users, and i use websecurity for login and register things.

why sessoin is not strong like websecuty?

Comment: Each of them has their own time out period that you can configure.

Comment: @SystemDown how to make these times equal?